# Find the ferquency of values within an interval in Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe and a column in the dataframe has these values.

```
df['column'] = [84.0, 85.0, 75.0, nan, 51.0, 50.0, 70.0, 85.0 ... ]
```

I am trying to get the frequency of getting a value between an interval like

```
freq = {
    15 : 40,  # number of values between 10 and 20 were 40. (mean taken to be 15)
    25 : 47,  # number of values between 20 and 30 were 47. (mean taken to be 25)
    ...
}
```

Is there any specific function in pandas to do this kind of operation rather than making a for loop and checking each value and incrementing the count in the freq dictionary?

[Edit] my goal is to get a dictionary like this and then to replace `NaN` with `freq.keys()` in the ratio of `freq.values()`

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by interval here? First ten indices? and then the next ten etc? Or the actual values between 0-10 count and then next 11-20 counts?

Comment: not the indices. The number of actual values in 0-10 interval and then the number of actual values in 10-20 interval, etc

i.e. if I sort it, then I get an array like [0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 13, 13, 14, ...]. In this case, the number of values between 0 and 10 would be 6. So in the dictionary freq, the entry would be 5 : 6 (here 5 is used as a key because it is the mean of 0 and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create intervals
bins = pd.interval_range(0, 100, freq=10)

# assign each value in df["column"] to bin and count bin occurences
counts = pd.cut(df["column"], bins).value_counts()

# create a Series, indexed by interval midpoints and convert to dictionary
pd.Series(counts.values, index=bins.mid).to_dict()
```